# How can I avoid repetition of the same number?

Tags: java, arrays, function, for-loop

This is what I want :
Let the user enter as many numbers as they want until a non number is entered (you may
assume there will be less than 100 numbers). Find the most frequently entered number. (If
there are more than one, print all of them.)
Example output:
Input: 5
Input: 4
Input: 9
Input: 9
Input: 4
Input: 1
Input: a
Most common: 4, 9
I have got to the point in my code where I have managed to find out which are the most common numbers. However, I don't want to print out the same number over and over again; example from above: Most common: 4, 9, 9, 4
What needs to be done?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[] input = new String[100];
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    input[0] = in.readLine();
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100 && isNumeric(input[i-1]); i++) {
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            input[i] = in.readLine();
            size = size + 1;
    }
    /*for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //testing
        System.out.println(input[i]);
    }*/
    int numOccur;
    int[] occur = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        numOccur = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if(input[i].equals(input[j])) {
                numOccur = numOccur + 1;
            }
        }
        occur[i] = numOccur;
        //System.out.println(numOccur); //testing
    }
    int maxOccur = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(occur[i] > maxOccur) {
            maxOccur = occur[i];
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(maxOccur); //testing
    for (int i = 0; i < size && !numFound; i++) {
        if(occur[i] == maxOccur) {
           System.out.println(input[i]);
        }
    }

}

//checks if s is an in, true if it is an int
public static boolean isNumeric (String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true; //parse was successful
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Found the solution!

```
String[] mostCommon = new String[size];
    int numMostCommon = 0;
    boolean numFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int isDifferent = 0;
        if (occur[i] == maxOccur) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (!(input[i].equals(mostCommon[j]))) {
                    isDifferent = isDifferent + 1;
                }
            }
            if (isDifferent == size) {
                mostCommon[numMostCommon] = input[i];
                numMostCommon = numMostCommon + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numMostCommon - 1; i++) {
        System.out.print("Most common: " + mostCommon[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println(mostCommon[numMostCommon - 1]);
```

Comment: yeap, sorry forgot to add the tag.
i have only learned functions, arrays, for & while loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Set<Integer> uniqueMaxOccur = new HashSet<Integer>();  
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
        if(occur[i] == maxOccur) {
            //System.out.println(input[i]);
            uniqueMaxOccur.add(input[i]);
        }
    }
```

and display the values in the set

Comment: Could you explain, I'm not familiar with using a set. Additionally, are there other ways of doing it?

Comment: It is logically best to use set you can find the Set tutorial[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html). Hint you have to use an iterator.

Comment: To work without set is not recommended and all I can think of is you have to store every number printed in an array of size  `size/maxoccur` and add the numbers in this array. Before printing you have to check all the items for duplicacy. But again I will recommend you using a set.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the hash table for this to store the frequenceis as the limit is very less i.e. less than 100.
pseudo code would be like:

    `vector<int> hash(101)`
    `cin>>input`
    `if(isnumeric(input))`
       `hash[input]++`
   `else{`
         `max=max_element(hash.begin(),hash.end());`
         `for(int i=0;i<100;i++)`
            `if(hash[i]==max)`
                `print i`
   `}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and store the values already printed.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Map<string,int> numberLookup = new HashMap<string,int>();
    Boolean doContinue = true;
    while (doContinue)
    {
        System.out.print("Input: ");
        String input = in.readLine();
        if (isNumeric(input))
        {
            if (!numberLookup.containsKey(input))
                numberLookup.put(input,1);
            else
                numberLookup.put(input, numberLookup.get(input) + 1);
        }
        else
            doContinue = false;
    }

    maxOccur = numberLookup.values().max();
    System.out.print("These numbers were all entered " + maxOccur + " times:");
    Iterator it = numberLookup.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey());
    } 
}
```

Sorry, I'm a C# person and don't have a Java compiler on me, so this might need some tweaking.